# Размещение телеграмбота на сервер

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Возникла проблема насчёт сервера для бота который написан на питоне.
Сначала размещал бота на pythonanywhere, после того как я поменял библиотеку для кода, да и вообще можно сказать переписал его. Начались проблемы с данным сервисом, а точнее что он не поддерживает библиотеку которую мне надо.
Вопрос такой можно ли найти бесплатно место для своего бота, или можно найти подходящую библиотеку и переписать код и выложить на pythonanywhere?
Писал бота сразу говорю что не на pyTelegramApi :)

Comment: Пробовали Heroku?

Comment: @Стас кстати не пробовал, как раз попробую завтра.Спасибо за ответ, возможно вы мне помогли :)

Comment: На Heroku с 28 ноября будет невозможно бесплатное размещение.

Comment: бесплатно можно на своем компьютере разместить...ну и то - за эл-во и коммуналку платить все равно придется.

Comment: Можно и на старом смартфоне, или планшете линукс сервер сделать. И на нём запустить. Только розетка лишная понадобится.